# camel file sortBy and poll failed

Tags: apache-camel

I have this endpoint :

```
 <from
                           uri="file://{{incomingFileBaseFolder}}?filter=#fileFilter&amp;recursive=true&amp;readLock=changed&amp;move=${file:parent}/.backup/${date:now:yyyy}/backup_${exchangeId}_${file:onlyname.noext}.${file:name.ext}&amp;sortBy=file:modified&amp;delay={{incomingFileDelay}}" />
```

So it is sorted by file:modified .
My question is what happen when the pull failed . Will the next poll move to the next file in the directory , or will it stay with the failed file ?

Answer (score 1):

By default it will leave the failed file in the directory and proceed with the rest. But it's better to define the `moveFailed` URI option to specify a "failed" directory. For more info on **moveFailed** [take a look at the Documentantion](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html).

Comment: yes thank you , I know about the moveFailed , but I prefer to live the file in the origin directory in order to let the application keep trying to poll it, But I prefer camel will not stick with this file but poll other files first if exist in the directory.